# How to upgrade Glass Mapper code that uses AbstractGlassUserControl?

Tags: glass-mapper

I am upgrading some Glass Mapper code that I inherited.  The previous version of Glass Mapper was v3 and I am upgrading to v5.3.17.

I have a class that looks like this:

```
public class MyRepository : AbstractGlassUserControl
{
  ...code here
}
```

When I upgraded the Glass Mapper DLLs and tried to build I got an error saying that this class now requires a constructor that passes in an `IWebFormsContext`.  So I made that change and now the class looks like this...

```
public class MyRepository : AbstractGlassUserControl
{
  public MyRepository(IWebFormsContext context) : base(context)
  {
  }
  ... code here
}
```

But now I have other problems elsewhere in the code.  In a different class I have code that creates an instance of this repository like this...

```
private MyRepository _repository = new MyRepository();
```

It isn't clear to me how I can pass in the necessary `IWebFormsContext` object here when I am trying to create an instance of this repository.

Can anyone help me understand how I can create an instance of `MyRepository` and pass in the necessary context?

Comment: I believe this post contains all the answers https://www.coreysmith.co/glass-mapper-5-dependency-injection/

Comment: Yes I read through that post.  But it didn't really make sense to me and it wasn't exactly clear what I need to do.  :)  Perhaps I just don't understand enough about Dependency Injection and how it works.

Comment: So maybe this is a better start https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/dependency_injection ?